# Text Color not changing on click

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a List View and i am setting the background of the list item with the selector.

list_selecter.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- focused and pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@color/darkred" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_pressed="false"/>
<!-- pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@color/darkred"/>
```

Layout for the List Item is :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/list_selecter"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/newsHeadingText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/text_selector" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/aerow" />


<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/newsText"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/newsHeadingText"
    android:textColor="#736F6E" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the text_selector.xml for the text color change:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
  <item android:color="@android:color/black"/>

 </selector>
```

Text color is not getting changed on the selection. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `android:duplicateParentState='true'` on your `TextView`

Comment: Thanks Kapil. It worked. But could you tell me the reason for using that.

Comment: because the parent of textview is also selectable

Comment: Didn't work for me, must be something else getting in the way.